# Cannot create cache directory .. or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache in RainTPL

Tags: php, task-parallel-library, raintpl

I Created one New RainTPL Project. When I go to my file Index.html to see the result Display Following Error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Rain\Tpl\Exception: **Cache directory
>   cache/doesn't have write permission.** Set write permission or set
>   RAINTPL_CHECK_TEMPLATE_UPDATE to FALSE. More details on
>   http://www.raintpl.com/Documentation/Documentation-for-PHP-developers/Configuration/
>   in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aLittleBitOfPhp/tpl/vendor/rain/raintpl/library/Rain/Tpl/Parser.php:223
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aLittleBitOfPhp/tpl/vendor/rain/raintpl/library/Rain/Tpl.php(262):
>   Rain\Tpl\Parser->compileFile('index', NULL, 'tpl/', 'tpl/index.html',
>   'cache/index.6f6...') #1
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aLittleBitOfPhp/tpl/vendor/rain/raintpl/library/Rain/Tpl.php(63):
>   Rain\Tpl->checkTemplate('index') #2
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aLittleBitOfPhp/tpl/index.php(20):
>   Rain\Tpl->draw('index') #3 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aLittleBitOfPhp/tpl/vendor/rain/raintpl/library/Rain/Tpl/Parser.php
>   on line 223

Then when I go to Terminal to install use:

```
chmod 777 ./cache
chmod 755 ./cache
chown -R admin  ./cache
```

Display Following Error.

```
chmod: ./cache: No such file or directory
```

and

```
chown: ./cache: No such file or directory
```

I am using macOS Sierra

Comment: Can you try again without `./` part or full path?

Comment: it worked on the tpl dir and now its working thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then the right way to do this is just do it without `./`

You must go on the project directory and use this on terminal.

```
chmod 777 cache
```

Thank you [mim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2629508/mim) for your help.